# How to crop imagedata after a registration?

Tags: c++, image-processing, vtk, medical

This is a question about vtk program.

I'm making a rigid registration between 3D MRI and 3D US image. The size of US data is much bigger than MRI. First, I take some landmarks on the same organ of both images.Then, I use "vtkLandmarkTransform" to get a transform between these landmark points. At last I apply the transform to MRI data by using "vtkImageReslice". So I get a huge MRI data.

How can I crop the huge data to make the new MRI data have the same size as US image and show the same organ position as US image?

Hers's my code

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> sourcePoints = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();//Input source points
for ( int t = 0; t < 6; t++ )
{
    float sourcePoint[3] = {inital_points_mri[t][0], inital_points_mri[t][1], inital_points_mri[t][2]};
    sourcePoints->InsertNextPoint(sourcePoint);
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> targetPoints = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();//Input target points
for ( int t = 0; t < 6; t++ )
{
    float targetPoint[3] = {inital_points_us[t][0], inital_points_us[t][1], inital_points_us[t][2]};
    targetPoints->InsertNextPoint(targetPoint);
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkLandmarkTransform> landmarkTransform = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLandmarkTransform>::New();//get landmark transform
landmarkTransform->SetSourceLandmarks(sourcePoints);
landmarkTransform->SetTargetLandmarks(targetPoints);
landmarkTransform->SetModeToSimilarity ();
landmarkTransform->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice> transform2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice>::New(); // Apply transform
transform2->SetInput(MRIimagedata); // Input MRI image
transform2->AutoCropOutputOn();  // I'm not sure I need it or not?
// transform2->SetOutputExtent(0,499,0,489,0,358); // set the extent as US data, but can't get the same organ position
landmarkTransform->Inverse();
transform2->SetResliceTransform(landmarkTransform);
transform2->Update();
vtkImageData* transformImage = transform2->GetOutput();
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I also asked the question in vtk-user mail list. But no replays received. So please don't suggest me to do that :)

Comment: "How can I crop the huge data to make the new MRI data have the same size as US image" 
If the two image data have the same size, how can you crop? Do you mean you want to resize it to a smaller size?

Comment: @TianyunLing No they don't not have the same size. I make a transform between landmarks on organs of images. So the transform will keep the organs have same size but not the images.

Comment: can you supply what is roughly the geometry (spacing, size, origin) of these images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, guys. I made a stupid mistake in this part.

I take landmarks of MRI on a coordinate with origin (0, 0, 0). Then I apply the transform to MRI data but forget that the offset of MRI data is not (0, 0, 0). That why I can't get the right result.

Back to my question: How to crop image data by using VTK? 
The answer is very simple: Set output origin and extend parameters by using following code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice> transform2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice>::New();
transform2->SetInput(MRIimagedata);
// transform2->AutoCropOutputOn();  //It's not necessary 
landmarkTransform1->Inverse();
transform2->SetResliceTransform(landmarkTransform1);
transform2->SetOutputOrigin(0,0,0);  //set the origin of new image data. It's where we start our crop
transform2->SetOutputExtent(0,499,0,489,0,358);  //set the range to crop from big data
```

If the transform is correct, you will get the right result.

Here's my code

```
// read MRI image data
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> reader1 =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>::New();
reader1->SetFileName("MRI.mhd");
reader1->Update();
vtkImageData* MRIimagedata = reader1->GetOutput();
double* origin_MRI = MRIimagedata->GetOrigin();

// generate landmark transforms
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> sourcePoints1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();//Input landmarks on MRI data, should add the offset of MRI data
for ( int t = 0; t < 6; t++ )
{
    float sourcePoint1[3] = {inital_points_mri[t][0]+origin_MRI[0], inital_points_mri[t][1]+origin_MRI[1], inital_points_mri[t][2]+origin_MRI[2]};
    sourcePoints1->InsertNextPoint(sourcePoint1);
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> targetPoints1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();//input landmarks on US data, the offset of US is (0,0,0)
for ( int t = 0; t < 6; t++ )
{
    float targetPoint1[3] = {inital_points_us[t][0], inital_points_us[t][1], inital_points_us[t][2]};
    targetPoints1->InsertNextPoint(targetPoint1);
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkLandmarkTransform> landmarkTransform1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLandmarkTransform>::New();
landmarkTransform1->SetSourceLandmarks(sourcePoints1);
landmarkTransform1->SetTargetLandmarks(targetPoints1);
landmarkTransform1->SetModeToSimilarity();
landmarkTransform1->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice> transform2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice>::New();
transform2->SetInput(MRIimagedata);
// transform2->AutoCropOutputOn();
landmarkTransform1->Inverse();
transform2->SetResliceTransform(landmarkTransform1);
transform2->SetOutputOrigin(0,0,0);
transform2->SetOutputExtent(0,499,0,489,0,358);
transform2->Update();
vtkImageData* transformImage = transform2->GetOutput();
```